# How to print elements of an array character or number wise in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have created below code:

```
<?php

$arry = array('Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici', '2222', 'Calvin', 'Gran', '2121', '1001', '11545', '9090');

sort($arry);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arry);



for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++) {
echo '<Br/><h2>'.$i.'</h2>';    
    foreach($arry as $s) {
        if ($s[0] == $i) {

            echo $s.' - ';
        }
    }
}

for($c='A',$j=1;$j<=26;$j++) {
                echo '<Br/><h2>'.$c.'</h2>';
    foreach($arry as $s) {

        if ($s[0] == $c) {

            echo $s.' - ';
        }
    }
    $c++;
}
```

Output of this code looks like below:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD4R0.png)

Now if you look into output it prints all characters and all numbers. even if the ones which doesn't have it's corresponding value

for ex:
Character "A" has four value 'Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici'
so it will print all four values because this character is matched with first characters of all four values

But character "B" is printed even if it doesn't have any value in the array

So how can I print only those characters(with value) which does have it's corresponding value in given array?

Please refer screenshot for further information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used your code and just altered it a bit. I inserted a `bool` to determine if it contains a value. If it does, then it will print, of not it will not print.

```
$arry = array('Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici', '2222', 'Calvin', 'Gran', '2121', 
'1001', '11545', '9090');

sort($arry);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arry);



for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++) {


$contains = false;

foreach($arry as $s) {
    if ($s[0] == $i) {

        $contains = true;
    }
}

if($contains){

    echo '<Br/><h2>'.$i.'</h2>'; 

}


foreach($arry as $s) {
    if ($s[0] == $i) {

        echo $s.' - ';
    }
}
}



for($c='A',$j=1;$j<=26;$j++) {

$contains2 = false;

foreach($arry as $s) {

    if ($s[0] == $c) {

        $contains2 = true;
    }
}

if($contains2){

    echo '<Br/><h2>'.$c.'</h2>';

}


foreach($arry as $s) {

    if ($s[0] == $c) {

        echo $s.' - ';
    }
}
$c++;
}
```

The Output:

```
1
1001 - 11545 - 
2
2121 - 2222 - 
9
9090 - 
A
Alan - Alesso - Alex - Avici - 
C
Calvin - 
G
Gran -
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your array format and this becomes trivial:

```
<?php
$arry = array('Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici', '2222', 'Calvin', 'Gran', '2121', '1001', '11545', '9090');
sort($arry);

foreach($arry as $v)
    $result[$v[0]][] = $v;

foreach($result as $k=>$v)
    echo "$k\n" . implode(', ', $v) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
1
1001, 11545
2
2121, 2222
9
9090
A
Alan, Alesso, Alex, Avici
C
Calvin
G
Gran
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to know if there are any matches before you output anything, so this code looks at each character (I've built 1 array which contains all the options using `range()`) and finds any matching elements.  Then if there are some matching elements it prints them out...

```
$arry = array('Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici', '2222', 'Calvin', 'Gran', '2121', '1001', '11545', '9090');

sort($arry);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arry);

$match = array_merge(range(1,9), range("A", "Z"));
foreach ( $match as $char ){
    // Create empty list
    $matches = [];
    foreach($arry as $s) {
        if ($s[0] == $char) {
            // Add match to list
            $matches[] = $s;
        }
    }
    // Check if any matches
    if ( count($matches) > 0 )  {
        echo '<Br/><h2>'.$char.'</h2>'.implode(" - ", $matches);
    }
}
```

The advantage of using 1 loop for all matches (numeric and character) is that you can make changes in 1 place if you want to add some more logic - or change the display of the output.

You could add some extra logic to say that as your list is sorted - if you have already found matches and the current item doesn't match then stop.  Which IMHO isn't worth it in such this case.

Answer (score 0):

so you need to check is there is smth before you do print the $i and $c:

```
<?php

$arry = array('Alex', 'Alan', 'Alesso', 'Avici', '2222', 'Calvin', 'Gran', '2121', '1001', '11545', '9090');

sort($arry);
echo '<pre>';print_r($arry);



for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++) {
    $tmp = '';
    foreach($arry as $s) {
        if ($s[0] == $i) {
            $tmp.= $s.' - ';
        }
    }
    if (!empty($tmp)) {
        echo '<Br/><h2>'.$i.'</h2>';
        echo $tmp;
    }
}

for($c='A',$j=1;$j<=26;$j++) {
    $tmp = '';
    foreach($arry as $s) {

        if ($s[0] == $c) {

            echo $s.' - ';
        }
    }
    $c++;
    if (!empty($tmp)) {
        echo '<Br/><h2>'.$c.'</h2>';
        echo $tmp;
    }
}
```

result:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [0] => 1001
    [1] => 2121
    [2] => 2222
    [3] => 9090
    [4] => 11545
    [5] => Alan
    [6] => Alesso
    [7] => Alex
    [8] => Avici
    [9] => Calvin
    [10] => Gran
)
<Br/><h2>1</h2>1001 - 11545 - <Br/><h2>2</h2>2121 - 2222 - <Br/><h2>9</h2>9090 - Alan - Alesso - Alex - Avici - Calvin - Gran -
```